# Variable scope with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript object which has a jquery ajax call to server to fill one of its attributes:

```
function Busqueda(contenedor){
    var datosPost = "someData";

    var resultados = undefined;
    var that = this;

    this.buscar = function(){
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "phpFile.php",
            data: datosPost,
            success: function (data){
                if(data.error != 0){
                    alert(data.errorTxt);
                } else {
                    that.resultados = data.resultados;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The ajax call should fill the attribute "resultados". However, after the "buscar" method is run, resultados remains undefined.

Also, I debugged "that.resultados" inside the success method and it is Busqueda's attribute.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using that.resultados? do you mean "this"? It should just be "resultados"

```
function Busqueda(contenedor){
    var datosPost = "someData";

    var resultados = undefined;
    var that = this;

    this.buscar = function(){
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "phpFile.php",
            data: datosPost,
            success: function (data){
                if(data.error != 0){
                    alert(data.errorTxt);
                } else {
                    resultados = data.resultados;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, since success() is a callback, he needs to use 'that', since 'this' will be bound to the window and not to Busqueda.

Comment: `resultados` is not a member of the `Busqueda` instance. It is a private variable, accessed by simple assignment and not any this/that dereference.

Comment: Tried without this/that, but didn't work. My code was based on this article: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Answer (score 0):

You never show how you use it. Are you properly creating an instance?

```
var o = new Busqueda();
// ... after the ajax success
console.log(o.resultados)
```

If you don't use `new` then `this` (and `that`) and will be `window`, not `o`.

Comment: var busqueda = new Busqueda($('#busquedaPersona'));        busqueda.buscar();